# Add user data to Firestore on sign up with Firebase Authentication with Google Sign-In with Swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I need to store some data in a "users" collection in the Firestore when the user signs in with Google for the first time on my iOS app. I am using Firebase Authentication. The data to be stored is:

- id: the user's UID
- display name: the user's full name
- photoURL: the url of the user's google account
- points: this will be 0 when the user first signs in
- knownLanguageCodes: this will be an empty array when the user first signs in

At the moment, nothing is saved to the Firestore.
This the section on my app delegate where signing in is handled.

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, GIDSignInDelegate {

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        FirebaseApp.configure()
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().clientID = FirebaseApp.app()?.options.clientID
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().delegate = self

        return true
    }

    //Only available on iOS 9 and later
    @available(iOS 9.0, *)
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any]) -> Bool {
        return GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handle(url)
    }

    func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInFor user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: Error?) { 
        if let error = error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
            return
        }

        guard let authentication = user.authentication else { return }
        let credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(withIDToken: authentication.idToken,
                                                 accessToken: authentication.accessToken)

        Auth.auth().signIn(with: credential) { (res, err) in

            if let err = err {
                print(err.localizedDescription)
                return
            }

            //I'm not sure if this block of code is in the right place
            let db = Firestore.firestore()
            db.collection("user").document(String((res?.user.uid)!)).setData([
                "id" : String((res?.user.uid)!),
                "displayName" : (res?.user.displayName)!,
                "photoURL" : (res?.user.photoURL)!
                "points" : 0
                "knownLanguageCodes" : []
            ], merge: true)
        } 
    }

    func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didDisconnectWith user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: Error!) {

    }
    //...
```

I'm using SwiftUI for the UI.

Answer (score 0):

Yes everything is correct but you are missing calling this function 
       GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signIn()

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `AppDelegate`, it is better to do this process in `UIViewController` on the action of `UIButton`. I think you are missing `GIDSignIn.sharedInstance()?.signIn()` and [this method should not be called when the app is starting up,
/// (e.g in `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`).](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/reference/Classes/GIDSignIn#/c:objc(cs)GIDSignIn(im)signIn) So you can try the following code for `UIButton` action

```
//rest of your code

if GIDSignIn.sharedInstance()?.hasPreviousSignIn() == true {

   //perform Your action if a user already sign in

} else {

  GIDSignIn.sharedInstance()?.signIn()

} 

//rest of your code
```